# Cannot add a child that doesn't have a CSS node to a node without a measure function

Tags: android, ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I upgraded to React Native v0.40 and an app that was working perfectly fine started to throw always that error.

[image]

Any clues?

This is the only file I found https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/ReactShadowNode.java after much research.

Comment: When is this error thrown?

Comment: When upgrading to react-native v0.40

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: I still have not upgraded, but I believe one could upgrade and rebuild most packages and it will work. If I make progress I will update this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

It turns out that I had an Icon component in a Text Component.
So I took the Icon out of it.

You may have similar incompatible components inside each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `react-native-svg`, make sure that you wrap any SVG components, like `<Circle .../>` inside of `<Svg> ... </Svg>` tags.

Otherwise, you get this error message.

Answer (score -2):

Try this It worked for me. 
Go to your react native project folder and run the below commands.

rm -r node_modules
npm install